# JQuery Scroll help end

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

So I've got the following code:

```
window.onload = function () {

function getScrollTop() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined') {
        // Most browsers
        return window.pageYOffset;
    }

    var d = document.documentElement;
    if (d.clientHeight) {
        // IE in standards mode
        return d.scrollTop;
    }

    // IE in quirks mode
    return document.body.scrollTop;
}

window.onscroll = function () {
    var reviewbasket = document.getElementById('reviewbasket'),
    scroll = getScrollTop();

    if (scroll > 950) {
        $("#global").stop;
    }
    else {
        reviewbasket.style.top = (scroll + 0) + "px";
    }
};

};
```

Currently the scroll ends at 950 px however I wish for the div to scroll right up until the max height of either the content area (#content) or the page is reached. I also don't want the div to overlap the footer. The main problem I face is that this page is viewed in two different states: Logged in and Logged out, Logged out comes with an extra content area which pushes the basket down further and stops me being able to set a fixed height for the scroll to end.

Any tips or direction is welcome!

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Please [accept answers to your previous questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), as this gives us an incentive to help you with future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to hold the height of your content div. Then, when the page changes state (Logged in => Logged out), call a function to update the height variable.

```
var maxScroll = $("#content").height();

function resetMaxScroll() {
    maxScroll = $("#content").height();
}

...

if (scroll > maxScroll) {
    $("#global").stop;
}
```